# Call a Fragment's method from parent Activity using a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, swipe

I have some sample code from Slidenerd's Scrolltab video series and this works perfectly well. However, I cannot call a method inside a fragment from the parent activity. For example, I have included a method inside fragment A called doSomething(). I'd like to call it from MainActivity's onResume() callback.

Edit:
Using the "accepted answer" works for this application but not for the actual application that I'm working on due to a nullpointerexception.

Error log

```
06-25 13:02:19.308    3862-3862/com.felhr.agweigh D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-25 13:02:19.308    3862-3862/com.felhr.agweigh W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416ecda0)
06-25 13:02:19.308    3862-3862/com.felhr.agweigh E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.felhr.agweigh, PID: 3862
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.felhr.usbservice.USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED flg=0x10 } in com.felhr.agweigh.MainActivity$3@41da2c10
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:782)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.felhr.agweigh.FragmentPlotCSV.createSpinner(FragmentPlotCSV.java:102)
            at com.felhr.agweigh.MainActivity$3.onReceive(MainActivity.java:894)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:772)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.felhr.agweigh" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:logo="@drawable/rinstrumlogo"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/RinstrumActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.felhr.agweigh.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.felhr.agweigh.UsbService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

MyAdapter

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
{
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Log.d("SWIPE","get Item is called"+i);
    if (i==0)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentA();
    }
    if (i==1)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentB();
    }
    if (i==2)
    {
        fragment=new FragmentC();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.d("SWIPE","get count is called");
    return 3;
}

// talks to title to give the page
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return "Tab 1";
    }
    if (position == 1) {
        return "Tab 2";
    }
    if (position == 2) {
        return "Tab 3";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

FragmentA

```
/**
 * Created by Luke on 20/04/2015.
 */
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        // call this method from main activity
        }
    }
```

FragmentB

```
/**
 * Created by Luke on 20/04/2015.
 */
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }
}
```

FragmentC

```
/**
 * Created by Luke on 20/04/2015.
 */
public class FragmentC extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this-

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        FragmentA _fragA = new FragmentA();
        _fragA.doSomething();

    }
```

You can register your receiver in the manifest file by using the  element:

```
       <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.Broadcast" >
                    </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The nested element  is used to specify the event the receiver should react to.

Comment: Are you implementing BroadCart Receiver too, then please show me your manifest of broadcast receiver part.

Comment: yeah, I am... essentially I am trying to run a method in FragmentReadCSV after receiving an intent that says the USB port is ready

Comment: please register your Receiver in manifest, i have give a sample for that. Please see my edits.

Comment: I did this but I think the issue is that I'm doing this in the BroadCast Receiver: 
                FragmentPlotCSV fragmentPlotCSV = new FragmentPlotCSV();
                fragmentPlotCSV.createSpinner();

Comment: Show that class, please

Comment: I'm getting in trouble for having an extended discussion in these comments - can I continue this via email?

Comment: I've made a dodgy work-around, where a timer is set in the fragment and it checks whether a Boolean is set in the activity. When the Boolean is set fragment calls the method and stops the timer. I'd prefer not to do this.

Comment: please add your receiver class in which you are facing this dilemma .

Comment: it's too large and I shouldn't share it publicly... can I email it to you?

Answer (score 3):

Just an fyi, your question isn't specific to using a ViewPager.

By design, the activity doesn't know anything about your FragmentA other than it being a Fragment, therefore it doesn't know it contains a doSomething() method. The quick and dirty way would be to get the fragment from the adapter and cast it to FragmentA when you know it is a FragmentA. I say this is a "quick and dirty" way because you want to keep things decoupled between activity and fragment--i.e. your activity shouldn't need to know about your FragmentA implementation and only know about Fragment.

As you build more complex apps, you'll want to look into using an event bus to send messages between fragments and activities in a nice decoupled way. Here are a few popular android event buses:
http://square.github.io/otto/
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus